# sails on heroku miss req.param() when upload file

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I am want to change User avatar, but when I am send in form userID and image, UserID is undefined on production(I am use Heroku), if I am send only UserID without image, server recive ID. On development(localmachine) all fine. Sails 0.11

```
avatar: function (req, res) {
    var userID = req.param('id');

    req.file('logo').upload(function (err, image) {

        if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
        if (image.length === 0) return res.badRequest('No file was uploaded');

        StorageService.createCloudinray().upload({
            image: image[0].fd,
            id: userID + '_avatar',
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            crop: 'limit',
        }).done(function (img) {
            User
                .update(userID, {avatar: img.secure_url})
                .exec(function (err, userID) {});
            return res.ok(img);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue. But `req.param` is an object. So to get the id you would most likely need to do `var userID = req.param.id`

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper?

Comment: Yes, I am use Skipper, and file is last field in formData

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into this open Skipper issue:

- https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper/issues/71

Skipper 0.11 has bugs with undefined ids over SSL connections.